# How to generate sentiment scores using predefined aspects with deberta-v3-base-absa-v1.1 Huggingface model?

Tags: python, nlp, huggingface-transformers, sentiment-analysis, large-language-model

I have a dataframe , where there is text in 1st column and predefine aspect in another column however there is no aspects defined for few text  ,for example row 2.

```
data = {
    'text': [
        "The camera quality of this phone is amazing.",
        "The belt is poor quality",
        "The battery life could be improved.",
        "The display is sharp and vibrant.",
        "The customer service was disappointing."
    ],
    'aspects': [
        ["camera", "phone"],
        [],
        ["battery", "life"],
        ["display"],
        ["customer service"]
    ]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I want to generate two things

1. using pre define aspect for the text, generate sentiment score
2. using text generate aspect and also the sentiment score from the package

Note: This package yangheng/deberta-v3-base-absa-v1.1

1)generate sentiment score based on predefine aspects

2)generate both aspect and it's respective sentiments

**Note Row 2 does not have predefine aspect**

**I tried and getting error**

```
import torch
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForSequenceClassification
import pandas as pd

# Load the ABSA model and tokenizer
model_name = "yangheng/deberta-v3-base-absa-v1.1"
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)
model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(model_name)




# Generate aspects and sentiments
aspects = []
sentiments = []

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    text = row['text']
    row_aspects = row['aspects']
    
    aspect_sentiments = []
    
    for aspect in row_aspects:
        inputs = tokenizer(text, aspect, return_tensors="pt")
        
        with torch.inference_mode():
            outputs = model(**inputs)
        
        predicted_sentiment = torch.argmax(outputs.logits).item()
        sentiment_label = model.config.id2label[predicted_sentiment]
        
        aspect_sentiments.append(f"{aspect}: {sentiment_label}")
    
    aspects.append(row_aspects)
    sentiments.append(aspect_sentiments)

# Add the generated aspects and sentiments to the DataFrame
df['generated_aspects'] = aspects
df['generated_sentiments'] = sentiments

# Print the updated DataFrame
print(df)
```

**generic example to use the package**

```
import torch
import torch.nn.functional as F
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForSequenceClassification

model_name = "yangheng/deberta-v3-base-absa-v1.1"
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)
model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(model_name)

aspects = ["food", "service"]
text = "The food was great but the service was terrible."
sentiment_aspect = {}
for aspect in aspects:
  inputs = tokenizer(text, aspect, return_tensors="pt")

  with torch.inference_mode():
    outputs = model(**inputs)

  scores = F.softmax(outputs.logits[0], dim=-1)
  label_id = torch.argmax(scores).item()
  sentiment_aspect[aspect] = (model.config.id2label[label_id], scores[label_id].item())

print(sentiment_aspect)
```

**Desired Output**

[image]

Comment: What error are you getting from your code snippet?

Comment: What is "text generated aspect"?

Comment: Using Text, extract aspect

Comment: @alvas my code works but with predfined aspects , However I  want to use the package and also extract the aspect and provide the sentiment for the extracted aspect as two seperate column in pandas

,I want to use my existing code

Comment: I'm not sure if the model you've chosen have keyword/aspect extraction features. It looks like a classifier only.

Comment: It does , it use https://github.com/yangheng95/PyABSA ,but with transformers I am having issues how to extract aspect

Comment: For that particular case, it'll be easier to use the package library. Otherwise asking the GitHub issue there might get you a more canonical answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specific to the `yangheng/deberta-v3-base-absa-v1.1` model this is the usage and you have to loop through the model one time per aspect:

```
# Load the ABSA model and tokenizer
model_name = "yangheng/deberta-v3-base-absa-v1.1"
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)
model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(model_name)

classifier = pipeline("text-classification", model=model, tokenizer=tokenizer)


for aspect in ['camera', 'phone']:
   print(aspect, classifier('The camera quality of this phone is amazing.',  text_pair=aspect))
```

[out]:

```
camera [{'label': 'Positive', 'score': 0.9967294931411743}]
phone [{'label': 'Neutral', 'score': 0.9472787380218506}]
```

---

To get the zero-shot classification scores in general, try using `pipeline`:

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForSequenceClassification
from transformers import pipeline


# Load the ABSA model and tokenizer
model_name = "yangheng/deberta-v3-base-absa-v1.1"
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)
model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(model_name)


pipe = pipeline("zero-shot-classification", model=model, tokenizer=tokenizer)

pipe("The camera quality of this phone is amazing.", candidate_labels=["camera", "phone"])
```

[out]:

```
{'sequence': 'The camera quality of this phone is amazing.',
 'labels': ['camera', 'phone'],
 'scores': [0.9036691784858704, 0.09633082151412964]}
```

---

Depending on what "text generated aspect" means, perhaps it's keyword extraction, and if so, doing a search on https://huggingface.co/models?search=keyword, gives this as the top downloaded model, https://huggingface.co/yanekyuk/bert-uncased-keyword-extractor

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForTokenClassification

tokenizer2 = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("yanekyuk/bert-uncased-keyword-extractor")
model2 = AutoModelForTokenClassification.from_pretrained("yanekyuk/bert-uncased-keyword-extractor")



def extract_aspect(text):
    extractor = pipeline("ner", model=model2, tokenizer=tokenizer2)
    phrasesids = []
    for tag in extractor(text):
        if tag['entity'].startswith('B'):
            phrasesids.append([tag['start'], tag['end']])
        if tag['entity'].startswith('I'):
            phrasesids[-1][-1] = tag['end']
    phrases = [text[p[0]:p[1]] for p in phrasesids]
    return phrases

text = "The camera quality of this phone is amazing."

extract_aspect(text)
```

[out]:

```
camera
```

Putting the extractor and classifier together:

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForSequenceClassification, AutoModelForTokenClassification
from transformers import pipeline


# Load the ABSA model and tokenizer
model_name = "yangheng/deberta-v3-base-absa-v1.1"
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)
model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(model_name)

classifier = pipeline("zero-shot-classification", model=model, tokenizer=tokenizer)

tokenizer2 = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("yanekyuk/bert-uncased-keyword-extractor")
model2 = AutoModelForTokenClassification.from_pretrained("yanekyuk/bert-uncased-keyword-extractor")


def extract_aspect(text):
    extractor = pipeline("ner", model=model2, tokenizer=tokenizer2)
    phrasesids = []
    for tag in extractor(text):
        if tag['entity'].startswith('B'):
            phrasesids.append([tag['start'], tag['end']])
        if tag['entity'].startswith('I'):
            phrasesids[-1][-1] = tag['end']
    phrases = [text[p[0]:p[1]] for p in phrasesids]
    return phrases

text = "The camera quality of this phone is amazing."

pipe(text, candidate_labels=extract_aspect(text))
```

[out]:

```
{'sequence': 'The camera quality of this phone is amazing.',
 'labels': ['camera'],
 'scores': [0.9983300566673279]}
```

---

#### Q: But the extracted keywords is not "right" or doesn't match the pre-defined ones?

A: No model is perfect and the model example above is a keyword extractor not a product aspect extractor. YMMV.

#### Q: Why isn't the zero-shot classifier giving me negative / positive labels?

A: The zero-shot classifier is labelling the data based on the extracted labels. Not a sentiment classifier.

Comment: I disagree a bit on the zeroshot part. The model receives: `[CLS] The camera quality of this phone is amazing. [SEP] "This example is camera [SEP]` and checks the logits of the positive label. That is why the phone gets `0.09633082151412964`.

Comment: I think it's funky too. Maybe it's better to not use zero-shot in this particular case. It forces the softmax but it looks like the desired behavior should be binary per class and not probabilities across classes.